# Read a csv file async - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv, mongoose

I am a beginner, I want to create a function that reads a csv file that contains name of teachers and find it in database.

Here is my code.

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
function findTeacher(req, res) {
    csv.parseFile(req.body.file)
    .on("data", async function(data) {
        var teacher = await Teachers.find({name: data});
        console.log(teacher);
    })
    .on("end", function() {
        console.log("end");
    });
}
```

My problem is why "end" prints first even if I use async and await.

Is there a way to print the teacher first before "end"?

Comment: What is the `csv` library you use?

Comment: csv = require("fast-csv")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know what csv parsing library you’re using, knowing that would help, but those event handlers are decoupled from the actual csv parsing. So the data event gets emitted, and your on data function is called, but it takes time (it’s an async function, writing to a database). The problem for you is that running your on data function doesn’t block the csv parser, which continues on and emits its “end” event while your on data function is still running. So you’re logging end when the csv parsing has finished, not when your event handler has finished.

The simplest way to handle this would be to read all the lines into a queue, process them, then log end.

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
function findTeacher(req, res) {
    var lines = [];
    csv.parseFile(req.body.file)
    .on("data", function(data) {
       lines.push(data);
    })
    .on("end", function() {
       lines.forEach(function(data) {
         var teacher = await Teachers.find({name: data});
         console.log(teacher);
       });
        console.log("end");
    });
}
```